# Where does the forward radial distortion equation come from in camera calibration?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm reading [Zhang's camera calibration paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr98-71.pdf) and came across the following two equations.

[image]

I don't have journal access to [2, 25] so I can only guess where these formulas were derived. The term radial distortion suggests to me that the equation of a circle

$r^2 = (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2$

is being employed somewhere.

But I don't quite understand where those polynomials come from exactly.

I'm also confused about what they mean by "normalization". I believe this means dividing by the focal length (in pixels) to create a unitless quantity?

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: I never used this model so cannot answer, but there are ways to get access to publications, such as sending a kind email to (one of) the author(s). Regarding "where those polynomials come from exactly" -> It is possible that they com from nowhere if they are used to model a lens distortion: a camera model assumes that a function with parameters can approximate the reality well enough given good enough parameters (which says nothing about the type of the function: polynomial, rational, etc...)

Comment: [2] can be found [here](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/pers/1971journal/aug/1971_aug_855-866.pdf).